# springboot run cloud profile locally

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I understand how springboot uses cloud profile and initialises/connects to services

For debug purposes, is there a way to connect to my dev cloud from local machine by pointing to a specific dev cloud config?

I use internal pivotal cloudfoundry

My config has

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@Profile("cloud")
```

And

```
@Autowired(required = false)
Cloud cloud;
```

I want to debug this locally if possible

Comment: What means "connect to my dev cloud from local machine"? Do you want to connect to dev env databases etc?

Comment: if you are in cloud profile, you can use predefined services by just name and use Cloud object if required